# g++ 4.5 can't find a friend function

Tags: c++, g++, friend

G'day!

I have a question around the use of `friend` in C++. Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <ostream>

struct F {
};

struct N {
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const N&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const F&);    
};

void foo(std::ostream &out) {
  F bar;
  out << bar;
}
```

My understanding always was, that `friend` is similar to `static` with the additional property that the `friend` function has access to the private part of the class. Under that assumption, the code should compile, since there is an `operator<<` that takes an `ostream&` and a (const) `F&`.

It appears that g++ 4.0 shares my thoughts on this, as it accepts that code. The much newer g++ 4.5(.2) however, rejects the code with the message:

```
ns.cc: In function 'void foo(std::ostream&)':
ns.cc:14:10: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << bar'
```

is g++ 4.5 wrong or am I (and g++ 4.0) wrong?

(The solution to move the friend declaration into the `F` class doesn't help, as the `operator<<` will need access to the private part of `N`.)

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Have you tried declaring the operator in the namespace proper ? I think it's a name look-up issue.

Comment: Actually, the classes `N` and `F` originally have been in a namespace `xml` and later I imported the whole namespace by `using namespace xml`. That made no difference!

Comment: as noted by Let_Me_Be the problem is an issue of anchoring the declaration into a context. `friend` does not anchor the declaration unless you define the function immediately.

Comment: If the name of a function is only introduced by a 'friend' declaration then it will only be found through argument dependent lookup (ISO 3.4.2).  There are lots of rules but in the example here any "operator<<" functions that are friends of 'F' will be visible.  It would seem that gcc 4.0 made all friends visible, including those of 'N', and so the code compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the operators outside the struct as well. Same error is reported by gcc 4.4.

```
#include <ostream>

struct F {
};

struct N {
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const N&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const F&);    
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const N&);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const F&);    

void foo(std::ostream &out) {
  F bar;
  out << bar;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that a friend declaration doesn't provide a global function declaration, unless you provide an inline implementation.

```
struct N {
   friend void func1() { }
   friend void func2();
   friend void func3();
};

void func3();

func1(); /* OK */
func2(); /* not OK */
func3(); /* OK */
```

Comment: I like your answer the most but I guess it's too terse to be selected :/

Comment: The friend being a definition or not is not relevant.  If the function is only declared (or defined) as a friend then it won't be explicitly named in the namespace.  It may be found by argument dependent lookup, but that won't apply to your examples as there are no arguments on the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trudging through the standard (FCD, n3242) since I saw the question

In **[class.friend]** one can read:

> 6) A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.
>
> 7) Such a function is implicitly inline. A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined. A friend function defined outside the class is not (3.4.1).
>
> 9) A name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration.

So, what happens here ?

```
struct F {
};

struct N {
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const F&);    
};
```

The friend declaration nominates this overload of `operator<<` to be a friend of `N`. However this overload has not been declared in a lexical scope (either namespace or class). Also, `7` does not apply because it is not defined within `N` either.

Therefore, when looking up the overloads of `operator<<` that can apply in:

```
void foo(std::ostream &out) {
  F bar;
  out << bar;
}
```

There is no valid overload (actually, it could be there is no overload at all).

You have two solutions:

- use `7`: define the function inline following the friend declaration.
- use `9`: declare the function in the namespace too

Because of `4` though:

> 4) A function first declared in a friend declaration has external linkage (3.5). Otherwise, the function retains its previous linkage (7.1.1).

I would recommend declaring it *prior* to the `friend` declaration to control its linkage, but it will rarely matters.

Comment: Defining the friend makes no difference to the visibility of the name.  Bullet 7 above refers to how the definition of the friend function is parsed.  For example, if `TYPE` refers to `void` outside of the class and `int` inside of the class, then a friend defined in the class sees `TYPE` as `int` *even* if `TYPE` is declared later in the class.  A friend defined outside of the class requires a qualified name to find `TYPE` in the class, ie. it is parsed as a namespace function.