# Weird behavior with operator defined as friend inside class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I don't understand what is going on in the following piece of code:

```
struct A { };

struct B {
  B() { }
  B(const A&) { }

  friend B operator*(const B&, const B&)
  {
    return B();
  }
};

int main()
{
  B x = A() * A();

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile (with both clang and gcc 4.9.2) I get an error message on the "B x = A() * A()" line; clang says "invalid operands to binary expression".

If I take the operator* definition from inside the class, everything is 100% ok!

```
struct A { };

struct B {
  B() { }
  B(const A&) { }

  friend B operator*(const B&, const B&);
};

B operator*(const B&, const B&)
{
  return B();
}

int main()
{
  B x = A() * A();

  return 0;
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: Since `operator*()` is defined inside the function as a friend, it can only be found by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), not normal unqualified lookup. This type of lookup requires that the arguments be exact types, not types that are implicitly convertible. When you declare the function outside, then it can be found by the normal unqualified lookup rules.

Comment: @Brian I think this has more to do with where the function is declared. There's also the issue of the arguments he's using in the expression; he expects `A` to be converted to `B`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not sure how it's different, but I guess I'll reopen it so you can add an answer to explain (wait, shouldn't you be able to reopen it yourself since you also have a c++ gold badge?)

Comment: @Brian Yes but wanted to know the reason it was closed first. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 AFAICT, the duplicate has the same issue: the friend operator is not being found because it wasn't declared at namespace scope, and ADL can't find it either because the argument type is not the same as the type of the class in which the friend is declared. What's the difference?

Comment: @Brian I guess that's the case, but from the OPs example I think he expected the constructor to be called to convert the `A`s to `B`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `operator*()` is defined inside the function as a friend, it can only be found by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), not normal unqualified lookup. This type of lookup requires that the arguments be exact types, not types that are implicitly convertible. This means the operator cannot be found even if `A` can be converted to `B`.

When you declare the function outside the class, then it can be found by the normal unqualified lookup rules.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what is going on. The expected conversion from A to B actually doesn't seem to be very relevant to the issue, as can be seen in the question Brian had linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391927/g-4-5-cant-find-a-friend-function).