# Nested (non-template) class within a template class not being recognized as defined

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am creating a Map (keys and values) that is a template.  It has a Visitor Interface (not the problem), a Wrapper (also not the problem), and an Iterator (the problem) nested inside of it.

Here is the hpp: http://pastebin.com/tVv3Xkgp

It is giving me 19 errors.

```
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Iterator'   c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\maptemplate\maptemplate\Map.hpp 58  1   MapTemplate  

Error   3   error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters    c:\users\zack\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\maptemplate\maptemplate\Map.hpp 58  1   MapTemplate
```

It seems to think Iterator isn't defined.  Plus apparently `operator<<()` has too few parameters.  I assume it's ignoring Iterator, since it takes 2 parameters.  Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Iterator` is a dependent type, so you need `typename util::Map<KeyType, ValueType>::Iterator&`

Comment: Wow thank you, that fixed it!  Now to address the issues in my app.

Comment: Now I'm getting a linking error.  It seems to not be able to find the definition for the operator as far as I can tell from googling. here's the new hpp: http://pastebin.com/ULdUyjSD

Comment: @Zackeezy Did you declare `operator<<` before the class?

Comment: No. It's at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @Zackeezy Then the compiler does not know what is `operator<<`. Put `template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>  class Map;` in front and follow that by the signature of `operator<<`.

Comment: But it's prototype is in the class definition as a friend function.  Is that not enough?  Should I move the implementation above the class definition?

Comment: @Zackeezy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391927/g-4-5-cant-find-a-friend-function

Comment: Where exactly does it need to be defined outside of the class?  I tried adding it right after Map's definition, and it doesn't like it.  I tried outside of the util namespace, and it doesn't like it.  I am not sure why it isn't linking.